# SQL - Grouping creating new columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Good morning,

I'm a bit stuck in this problem, I would like to know if it's possible to group by a column getting the rest of columns from this one in new dynamic columns.

I'm going to try to explain the problem with an example:

For example:

```
+-------+---------+-----+------+
| Class |  Name   | Age | Size |
+-------+---------+-----+------+
| 1     | Pepe    | 10  | S    | 
| 1     | Antonio | 12  | M    | 
| 2     | Rosa    | 13  | M    | 
| 2     | Antonio | 13  | S    | 
| 2     | Amparo  | 12  | S    |
| ...   | ...     | ... | ...  |
| n     | n       | n   | n    | 
+-------+---------+-----+------+
```

To get the result in this way:

```
+-------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-----+--------+-------+--------+
| Class | Name_1 | Age_1 | Size_1 |   Name_2   | Age_2 | Size_2 | Name_3 | Age_3 | Size_3 | ... | Name_n | Age_n | Size_n |
+-------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-----+--------+-------+--------+
|     1 | Pepe   |    10 | S      | Antonio    | 12    | M      |        |       |        |     |        |       |        |
|     2 | Rosa   |    13 | M      | Antonio    | 13    | S      | Amparo | 12    | S      |     |        |       |        |
+-------+--------+-------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------+-------+--------+-----+--------+-------+--------+
```

I was trying to solve it in BigQuery, using pivot but I didn't get the result I want it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "New dynamic columns" and SQL don't go together.  What you *can* do is create an array column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results:

class combined_class
1  "name_1:Pepe,age_1:10,size_1:Pepe,name_2:Antonio,age_2:12,size_2:Antonio"
2  "name_1:Rosa,age_1:13,size_1:Rosa,name_2:Antonio,age_2:13,size_2:Antonio,name_3:Amparo,age_3:12,size_3:Amparo"
```

#standardsql:

```
with data as (select 1  Class , 'Pepe' Name, '10' age , 'S' size 
union all 
select 1  Class , 'Antonio' Name, '12' age , 'M' size 
union all
select 2  Class , 'Rosa' Name,'13' age , 'M' size 
union all
select 2  Class , 'Antonio' Name, '13' age , 'S' size 
union all
select 2   Class , 'Amparo' Name, '12' age , 'S' size )

 
SELECT
  class,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING( combined_recs,",") combined_class
FROM (
  SELECT
    class,
    ARRAY_AGG( ARRAY_TO_STRING( [ names, ages, sizes ],",")) combined_recs
  FROM (
    SELECT
      class,
      CONCAT( 'name_', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class) AS String),':',name ) names,
      CONCAT( 'age_', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class) AS String),':',age ) ages,
      CONCAT( 'size_', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY class) AS String),':',name ) sizes
    FROM
      DATA )
  GROUP BY
    1)
```