# Rearrange data grouping and creating new columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-wrangling

I have a table like this:

| email | id |
| --- | --- |
| albert | 1 |
| jped | 2 |
| rufus | 3 |
| rufuscomp | 3 |
| cousruf | 3 |
| peter | 4 |
| peter2 | 4 |
| clarisse | 5 |
| johan | 6 |
| john | 7 |

And I would like to obtain a table like this:

| id | email_1 | email_ 2 | email_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | albert | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | jped | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | rufus | rufuscomp | cousruf |
| 4 | peter | peter2 | NULL |
| 5 | clarisse | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | johan | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | john | NULL | NULL |

I would like to do this in SQL language. So the algorythm should identify the maximum numbers of repetitions in company_id to prepare the number of columns it will have the new table, and then rearrange all the values.

I have found this [SQL - Grouping creating new columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394350/sql-grouping-creating-new-columns) but it's not working in SQL Server.

Comment: Two questions, why do you want multiple columns? It's an odd request and generally not recommended to do this unless you have to. Second, what version of SQL Server are you using? 
If you really want to do this, you should look for "dynamic SQL pivot" examples

Comment: the reason is that there are more tables that need to be joined with this tables using the id column, and the id is supposed to be a primary key in the new table created. If I join using the first table the id can not be the primary key, in that case I should choose one of the mails (but I can't know which one).

Comment: And the version is 18.10

Answer (score 0):

I wanna share the solution I have found. First of all I had to use the ROW_NUMBER() window function, then I followed exactly this: https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/

So the final code is this one:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [id],
            [number_of_row],
            [email]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    CONCAT(
                        'Email_',
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                            PARTITION BY id
                            ORDER BY
                                email
                        )
                    ) AS number_of_row,
                    email
                FROM
                    original_table
            ) AS table_2
    ) AS table_3 PIVOT (
        MAX([email]) FOR [number_of_row] IN (
            [Email_1],
            [Email_2],
            [Email_3]
        )
    ) AS pivot_table
```